# How to loop over XML tags using groovy script

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

I have an XML response with namespaces as below:

```
<tns:Envelope xmlns:tns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
     <tns:Body>
        <svc:response xmlns:svc="http://...serviceNameSpace" 
                    xmlns:ent="http://....entitiesNameSpace">
            <svc:customerList>
                <svc:customer>
                    <svc:nonIRDAssetInformationList>
                        <svc:nonIRDAssetInformation>
                            <ent:assetId>AssetId1</ent:assetId>
                            <ent:assetSerialNumber>SerialNum1</ent:assetSerialNumber>
                            <ent:assetType>AssetType1</ent:assetType>
                        </svc:nonIRDAssetInformation>
                        <svc:nonIRDAssetInformation>
                            <ent:assetId>AssetId2</ent:assetId>
                                             <ent:assetSerialNumber>SerialNum2</ent:assetSerialNumber>
                            <ent:assetType>AssetType2</ent:assetType>
                        </svc:nonIRDAssetInformation>
                    </svc:nonIRDAssetInformationList>
                </svc:customer>
            </svc:customerList>
        </svc:response >
    </tns:Body>
</tns:Envelope>
```

This response XML in the response window of SoapUi.
I have a specific value for "assetSerialNumber" that will return in the one of the "nonIRDAssetInformation" the index of which i am not sure.

Now my requirement is to loop over all the "nonIRDAssetInformation" to check which iteration has the specific value and i need to save the value of "assetId" tag.

I am new to groovy scripting, and i had written the below script after doing some research.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder

//def holder = new XmlHolder(messageExchange.responseContentAsXml)
def Envelope = new XmlParser().parseText(messageExchange.responseContentAsXml)
def tns_ns = new groovy.xml.Namespace("http://..../envelope/", "tns")
def ent_ns = new groovy.xml.Namespace("http://..../entities/", "ent")
def svc_ns = new groovy.xml.Namespace("http://..../services", "svc")

def root = new XmlSlurper().parse(Envelope)
def serialNum= specific value is saved here
def nonIRDAssetInformationList = root.'**'.findAll{
   it.name()=='nonIRDAssetInformation'
}
nonIRDAssetInformation.each{
    it.assetSerialNumber.text().contains(serialNum)
    messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue( "ClientAssetId",it.assetId.text() as String);
}
```

When i ran the script i'm getting the below error

> No signature of method: groovy.util.XmlSlurper.parse() is applicable
>   for argument types: (groovy.util.Node) values:
>   [{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope[attributes={};
>   value=[{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Header[attributes={};.....

Is there any one who can help me in getting a solution for this.

Comment: Why are you trying to parse the parsed output of XmlParser through XmlSlurper?

Comment: Can you not use a contains assertion? That will check your whole XML for the serial number. Unless you expect the serial number to be present elsewhere in the XML you should be all right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be trying to parse already parsed results (not sure why)

Something like this should work for you:

```
import groovy.xml.*

def envelope = new XmlSlurper().parseText(messageExchange.responseContentAsXml)
def serialNum = 'Num'

envelope.'**'
        .findAll { it.name() == 'nonIRDAssetInformation' }
        .findAll { it.assetSerialNumber.text().contains(serialNum) }
        .each {
            println it.assetId.text()
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Tim.It worked, and i could continue with my work.  Thank you very much. :)